# SQL Server 2005 getting Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 16. in log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, authentication

SQL Server 2005 SP4 Standard Edition 32-bit.

One to a few times during the work day, seemingly at random, I am getting a log entry of "Login failed for user '*OurDomain*\mfreeman'. [CLIENT: 192.168.0.48]". This is paired with a log entry of "Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 16." at the same time.

This is my own login (which has the sysadmin role in the instance), and it is coming from my workstation.

I captured an example of this with Profiler and found that it is for the master database (which is online and not having any troubles -- I can run queries against it in SSMS just fine) and is coming from an ApplicationName of ".Net SqlClient" (which could be anything).
I am not getting any visible errors in any applcations (such as VS2012 with SSDT and Report Builder) or SSMS add-ins that I am using (ApexSQL Complete, SSMS Tools, Dell Spotlight Essentials).

Is there any way to find out more specifically what might be attempting the access or why it might be failing?

Answer (score 1):

State 16 means that the default database was inaccessible. This could be because the database has been removed, renamed, or is offline (it may be set to AutoClose). This state does not indicate a reason in the error log.

Resolve by fixing the missing database, or changing the login's default database using [`ALTER LOGIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), e.g.

```
ALTER LOGIN [your_login] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [valid_database];
```

This state may also be reported if the user's default database is online, but the database they explicitly requested in the connection string is not available for the reasons stated above.

Basically, either your login is explicitly asking for an invalid database, or it is implicitly doing so because its default database is not there.

Comment: Aaron, thanks for the response. I have no idea what is making the connection, and the connection is being made to the master database. As I stated in my post, I know that there is no problem with the master database in this database instance.

Comment: @Mark The error is logged in the master database, but that does not mean the user tried to connect to the master database. It would only show the database they tried to connect to if they were actually able to connect to it. Did you check the default database for the login `YOURDomain\mfreeman`? Did you try setting their default database explicitly, as suggested in my answer, to, say, tempdb? Did you look at any of the other columns you collected in Profiler (e.g. HostName, ApplicationName)?

Comment: I can't check or change the default database in the connection string for the client because I haven't been able to identify the client. The HostName is my machine and the ApplicationName is ".Net SqlClient". I will change the default database to tempdb for the domain group that my domain login is a member of as you suggested and I'll see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

In my case what I found was that there was a "job" under the "SQL Server Agent" that was referencing a DB that had been deleted.

Comment: I changed jobs 6 months ago, so I can't verify if this was the case for me. However, there were no job failures reported at the time. I had all jobs set to email on failure.